# If $x_{n+1}=ax_{n}^b$, find $x_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given $x_{1}$, $a$, $b$, and $x_{n+1} = a  x_{n} ^ b$, find $x_{n}$.

I'm not really sure how to tackle this problem. I do know that with all $a$ and $b$ that I will be using, the sequence will converge to zero.

Also, if someone could help me out with tagging this question, that would be great!

Comment: Write down the first few terms. Do u see a pattern?

Comment: Or just change variable to $y_n = \ln x_n$, the resulting recurrence is very simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with a problem of this kind, usually the first thing to do is to compute some terms to get an idea of what could be the solution. In your case:

$x_2 = a\cdot x_1^b$, $x_3 = a\cdot x_2^b = a^{b+1}x_1^{2b}$, $x_4 = a\cdot x_3^b = a^{b(b+1)+1}x_1^{3b}$ and so on. We see that every term is of the form $a^kx_1^l$. A good hypothesis, looking at the first terms is $x_n = a^{c_n}x_1^{(n-1)b}$ for every $n\geq2$, where $c_2 = 1$ and $c_{n+1}=bc_n+1$. Can you prove this (by induction)? Can you derive an explicit form for the $c_n$'s?

Comment: I see the pattern, and I see how to solve it with a $n-2$ degree polynomial, but I can't see an explicit formula.

Comment: Looking at the first terms, you should get $c_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}b^k$.